# Prevent user from download video file from html5 videoplayer

Tags: angularjs, html, video, youtube

I use Html 5 video playing feature to play video content on my angularJs web application. For this purpose I have to include the URL of source file in html, So user can easily access the original file on my server and download it directly. Also a download manager software can fetch the video from the page. What is the solution to prevent user from downloading videos of my website? How Websites like Youtube restrict user access to their videos?

Comment: You can still download videos from Youtube fairly easily...

Comment: Even if you somehow block users from downloading videos, they can still record their screen + audio using various other tools.

Comment: @JoseM for downloading youtube videos third party apps are needed. Is it possible to download them directly from youtube webpage?

Comment: @Mohamad Where do you think those third party apps are downloading it form? Youtube does a fairly good job hiding the source URL. But once you know how to get the URL, they cant stop you from downloading it. Because the server doesn't know the difference between the player or a spoofed user agent.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible without DRM. This is no way for the server to know what user agent is downloading, as user agents are self reported.

Comment: Can you explain more about DRM?

Comment: DRM is a very large topic. Start with wikipedia and google.